# Github pages site for both user and repo

Tags: github-pages

I have a site published to `user.github.io`, and now I'm trying to add a new pages deployment for the repository `user/repo` which *should* show up at `user.github.io/repo` if everything was working as expected. When I visit the latter I get errors about files not being found from `user.github.io`. This leads me to believe that the site at the root, `user.github.io`, is causing the page to try to load files from it instead of the one that is under `/repo`.

The `index.html` file when it's read by visiting `user.github.io/repo`:

[image]

The console errors showing the files failing to load:

[image]

Explicit path to the resource showing that it is available:

[image]

I assume there's a way to do this because it seems goofy that you wouldn't be able to have both a pages site for both your user and repositories that your user owns. I'm open to any suggestions here, my internet searching hasn't found anything useful.